# Adding files to SVN through a batch file

Tags: svn

I am trying to automate some routine chores such as, adding files and committing them in SVN. When I try the following in command line it works like a charm, but when I pass the same command through a batch file, it dose not work. Help!!

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:add/path:"D:\My Tasks\My test directory\concepts\test_file.txt"
```

I tried prefixing `START cmd.exe /k`, but it did not help.

Comment: How did you name your batch file ? Can you try to name it "myScript.bat" and double-click on it. What happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys. I don't know what went wrong when i tried to run the command from batch file, but now I got it right.

This time I tries the following command:

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:add /path:"D:\My Tasks\My test directory\concepts\test_file.txt"
```

Once again, thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried keeping the cmd open after you run the command?

For example, at the end of your batch file add:

```
cmd /k my_script.bat
```

Comment: Do you mean `cmd /k "TortoiseProc.exe /command:add/path:D:\My Tasks\My test directory\concepts\test_file.txt"`? I am a novice to batch files. Can you elaborate the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't even know TortoiseSVN exposes a client utility. Still, I'd recommend using the [Subversion CLI](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows) as it is tried and tested. In fact, [even TortoiseSVN's documentation states](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) (emphasis mine):

> Remember that TortoiseSVN is a GUI client, and this automation guide
>   shows you how to make the TortoiseSVN dialogs appear to collect user
>   input. If you want to write a script which requires no input, **you
>   should use the official Subversion command line client instead**.